# How to check if contact information exists in my Outlook contacts list?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, excel-2013

I have code which adds contacts from a worksheet to my Outlook contacts. Each Contact is on a separate line and has 5 columns with First Name, Last name, Email Address, Company and Mobilephone Number.

How do I add only those lines from the worksheet, which aren't in my contacts, so it doesn't create duplicates?

```
Sub ExcelWorksheetDataAddToOutlookContacts3()
    
    Dim oApplOutlook As Object
    Dim oNsOutlook As Object
    Dim oCFolder As Object
    Dim oDelFolder As Object
    Dim oCItem As Object
    Dim oDelItems As Object
    Dim lLastRow As Long, i As Long, n As Long, c As Long
    
    'determine last data row in the worksheet:
    lLastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Create a new instance of the Outlook application,
    ' if an existing Outlook object is not available.
    'Set the Application object as follows:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oApplOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    
    'if an instance of an existing Outlook object is not available,
    ' an error will occur (Err.Number = 0 means no error):
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oApplOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If
    
    'disable error handling:
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'use the GetNameSpace method to instantiate
    ' (ie. create an instance) a NameSpace object variable,
    ' to access existing Outlook items.
    'Set the NameSpace object as follows:
    Set oNsOutlook = oApplOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    '----------------------------
    
    'Empty the Deleted Items folder in Outlook so that
    ' when you quit the Outlook application you bypass the prompt:
    ' Are you sure you want to permanently delete all the items
    '  and subfolders in the "Deleted Items" folder?
    
    'set the default Deleted Items folder:
    'The numerical value of olFolderDeletedItems is 3.
    'The following code has replaced the Outlook's built-in 
    ' constant olFolderDeletedItems by its numerical value 3.
    Set oDelFolder = oNsOutlook.GetDefaultFolder(3)
    'set the items collection:
    Set oDelItems = oDelFolder.Items
    
    'determine number of items in the collection:
    c = oDelItems.Count
    
    'start deleting from the last item:
    For n = c To 1 Step -1
        oDelItems(n).Delete
    Next n
    
    '----------------------------
    
    'set reference to the default Contact Items folder:
    'The numerical value of olFolderContacts is 10.
    'The following code has replaced the Outlook's built-in 
    ' constant olFolderContacts by its numerical value 10.
    Set oCFolder = oNsOutlook.GetDefaultFolder(10)
    
    'post each row's data on a separate contact item form:
    For i = 2 To lLastRow
    
        'Using the Items.Add Method to create
        ' a new Outlook contact item in the default Contacts folder.
        Set oCItem = oCFolder.Items.Add
        'display the new contact item form:
        oCItem.Display
        
        'set properties of the new contact item:
        With oCItem
            .firstName = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
            .LastName = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2)
            .Email1Address = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3)
            .CompanyName = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4)
            .MobileTelephoneNumber = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5)
        End With
        
        'close the new contact item form after saving:
        'The numerical value of olSave is 0.
        'The following code has replaced the Outlook's built-in
        ' constant olSave by its numerical value 0.
        oCItem.Close 0
    
    Next i
    
    'quit the Oulook application:
    oApplOutlook.Quit
    
    'clear the variables:
    Set oApplOutlook = Nothing
    Set oNsOutlook = Nothing
    Set oCFolder = Nothing
    Set oDelFolder = Nothing
    Set oCItem = Nothing
    Set oDelItems = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Successfully Exported Worksheet Data to the Default Outlook Contacts Folder."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying? Here is a very basic fuction which uses `Outlook Items.Find` property to check if the email address exists in the address book.

```
Option Explicit

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutNs As Object
Dim OutFolder As Object
Dim OutItems As Object

Const olFolderContacts As Integer = 10

Sub Sample()
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutNs = OutApp.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
    Set OutFolder = OutNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
    Set OutItems = OutFolder.items
    
    Dim EmailToFind As String
    '~~> Change email here
    EmailToFind = "Sid@Sid.Com"
    
    MsgBox DoesContactExists(EmailToFind)
End Sub

'~~> Function to check if the email exists
Private Function DoesContactExists(EmailAddress As String) As Boolean
    Dim olContact As Object
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olContact = OutItems.Find("[Email1Address] = '" & name & "'")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not olContact Is Nothing Then DoesContactExists = True
End Function
```